# How to calculate different between date, which is in 1 column in R package dplyr?

Tags: r, case, dplyr, datediff

I have issue in R in dplyr.
First I want to calculate different bettwen date in days and then I want to group by status. I don't have idea.
I need this first step, because I need to get mean of days from each status.
I order my table by serial and date like this and I'm stuck. I use dplyr.

```
serial      a       b       status           date
312313124   27080   27030   Good Stock         20/01/2021 
312313124   27030   27009   Under Assessment   29/01/2021
312313124   27009   27080   In Repair          03/02/2021
70453423040 27080   27030   Good Stock         18/03/2021
70453423040 27030   27009   Under Assessment   25/03/2021
70453423040 27009   27080   In Repair          28/03/2021
12131231    27080   27030   Good Stock         03/07/2021
12131231    27030   60003   Active at          14/07/2021
12131231    60003   27008   Bad Stock          24/11/2021
12131231    27008   27009   Under Assessment   26/11/2021
12131231    27009   27030   Good Stock         29/11/2021
878678678   27030   60003   Active at          11/12/2021
878678678   60003   27008   Bad Stock          21/12/2021
```

I use this but I have error in mutate:

```
pivot <- Elavon_dis %>%
  mutate(diffdays = diff(Elavon_dis$Exported)) %>%
  group_by(serial, status, date, diffdays) %>%
  summarize(m_days = mean(status))
```

I want to see the difference in days between each status of the serial:

```
serial      a       b       status             date        days
312313124   27080   27030   Good Stock         20/01/2021    0
312313124   27030   27009   Under Assessment   29/01/2021    9
312313124   27009   27080   In Repair          03/02/2021    5
70453423040 27080   27030   Good Stock         18/03/2021    0
70453423040 27030   27009   Under Assessment   25/03/2021    7
70453423040 27009   27080   In Repair          28/03/2021    3
12131231    27080   27030   Good Stock         03/07/2021    0
12131231    27030   60003   Active at          14/07/2021    11
etc.
```

Kind regards,
Mati

Comment: First, you'll need `Date`-class objects, nothing in R is going to sanely work with `"20/01/2021"` for differencing. Second, `c(0, as.numeric(diff(date), units="days"))` should work, assuming you've used `group_by(serial)` in your pipe.

Comment: Your data is a little harder to just scoop up with a copy/paste, please post the output from `dput(dat)`.

Comment: please provide a code to reproduce a sample by using `dput(df)` (df is your dataframe)

Comment: I simplify my df. I can't use diff(date) because I don't want to calculate days between different of serial . How to get this column days?